# React Router + back button is resetting my app state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router Dom and the BrowserRouter object to enable browser based navigation for a site I'm building. Navigation works well, but if a user hits the back button, the entirety of my App's state is wiped clean.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I've tried searching around, but all of the answers I've found don't mention why App state is getting reset.

Here's my implementation:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact render={()=><LandingPage/>}
        <Route path="/about" render={()=><About/>}
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Am I doing something glaringly wrong? Could anyone with experience working with React Router give me some advice? Thanks so much!

Comment: What gets reset and where is it stored?

Comment: How do you use BrowserHistory object here? In React Router v4 there is no `browserHistory` anymore. Are you creating a custom one?

Comment: @charlietfl
"What gets reset and where is it stored?"

The state object in each component on the site (in other words, all state objects). It's like hitting the back button is starting a fresh session instead of just going back one page.

Comment: @devserkan Apologies, I'm not using browserHistory, that's a typo. I'm using BrowserRouter.

Comment: Well that is expected. When you change routes the component in prior route unmounts. Going back will mount it gain with whatever default state is unless you use a state management store

Comment: OK. Can we see your `Link` codes in the related components?

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. It sounds like using a state management store is the proper way of handling this problem. Can you recommend a state management store solution? I read a bit about the History package, but it didn't seem up-to-date/appropriate for this usecase.

Comment: @devserkan I'm afraid they wouldn't be terribly helpful, as they're quite simple.

    <Link to="/about">

Comment: Depending on app complexity might be able to create a simple store yourself. Or use a more robust state management like redux or mobx

Comment: @charlietfl So react-router-dom doesn't handle any of that stuff? At all?

Comment: No...not a router's responsibility to deal with internal component state

Comment: @charlietfl That's a bummer. I'm glad to hear that it's not just me using the tool incorrectly, though. I'll check out Redux. Thanks Charlie.

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 5):

If someone like me has this problem in the future and comes here from Google, here's what's going on:

1. React Router doesn't store state between page loads. It just routes traffic between components and handles history, among other things.
2. You need a separate state management store to preserve state changes. (Redux was recommended).

Thanks @charlietfl for the info.